# Union of open sets in a topological space $(X, \tau)$

Tags: general-topology

Let $\{C_\lambda : \lambda \in \Lambda\}$ be a family of closed sets in $(X, \tau)$ then for each $\lambda \in \Lambda$ the set $G_\lambda  = X \setminus C_\lambda$ is an open set in $(X, \tau)$.

Show that  $$\bigcup \{ G_\lambda : \lambda \in \Lambda\} =  X  \setminus  \bigcap \{C_\lambda : \lambda \in \Lambda\}$$

Comment: This is true for any family of sets, not only for open sets. It is called De Morgan's law. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws for a reference

Comment: @Crostul ok but I can't relate it with de Morgan's law. Can you please show how to make use of de Morgan's law for this

Comment: You can find a proof here https://proofwiki.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_Laws_(Set_Theory)/Set_Difference/Family_of_Sets/Difference_with_Intersection

Comment: There should be $C_\lambda$ in the intersection, I fixed it and the formatting too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just de Morgan's law really, a quick reproof:

Suppose $x$ is in the LHS union. Then for some $\lambda_0 \in \Lambda$ we have $x \in G_{\lambda_0}$, which means that $x \notin C_{\lambda_0}$ and in particular $x \notin \bigcap \{C_\lambda: \lambda \in \Lambda\}$, and so $x$ is in the RHS.

The reverse inclusion is similar: not being in the intersection means it's not in at least one of the sets $C_\lambda$ so in that set's complement, so in the union of the complements.